# Animation alpha (under SurfaceView) not working

Tags: android, animation, view, surfaceview

I want to make animation like fadeIn-fadeOut when user click on capture button.
When I set alpha 1.0 on animatedView and android:fromAlpha="1.0", android:toAlpha="0.0" it work, but  I need reverse it. 
Here my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/animated_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:alpha="0.0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    />
</set>
```

And that's how I run it:

```
animClick = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.click);

@OnClick(R.id.button_capture)
void onCaptureClick() {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    animatedView.startAnimation(animClick);
}
```

And nothing happens, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting animation is not really a problem you have not arranged your layout correctly 
Please look at layout provided it will not be the same you want but you will be able to understand how you are going to fix it.

you are putting height ==> match_parent for every thing may be that is the reason you are not able to animate view.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/animated_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can use updated xml works fine here !!!

Comment: But I need to make View completely overlap SurfaceView

Comment: you may check updated answer use this xml file Hope it helps